# error: Initializer for optional binding must have Optional type, not 'DetailViewController'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass info back from my DetailViewController to my MasterViewController with is a TableView however I am getting an error in my code and am not to sure what the problem could be?

```
    @IBAction func saveDetails(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("saveDetails triggered")
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as! DetailViewController, person = sourceViewController.person {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update an existing contact.
            objects[selectedIndexPath.row] = person
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        } else {
            // Add a new contact.
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: objects.count, inSection: 0)
            objects.append(person)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if let` construct needs to be optional, so it can fail and thus take the `else` branch:

```
if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? DetailViewController, ...
```

Note `as?` instead of `as!`.

Comment: I changed that and it's changed the error to "error: Initializer for optional binding must have Optional type, not 'Person'"

Comment: I fixed the error, had to go and change where i created my person object... Had to change it from var person = Person(...) to var person = Person?()